# csharp_style_var_when_type_is_apparent seems to be inconsistent sometimes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

I have this code:

```
        public void Foo()
        {
            Program foo1 = this.ToProgram();

            Program foo2 = this.ToProgram2();
        }

        private Program ToProgram()
        {
            return null;
        }
        private Program ToProgram2()
        {
            return null;
        }
```

And this editorconfig:

```
[*.cs]

# IDE0008: Use explicit type
csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types =  false:suggestion
csharp_style_var_when_type_is_apparent = true:suggestion
csharp_style_var_elsewhere = false:suggestion
```

Notice that in the screenshot below in the case of `ToProgram` it suggest to use var while for `ToProgram2` it does not. I don't really understand why as these methods could very well return something completely different than a `Program` so using var here is not really desired in my opinion. It only seems to happen when the method name is of the form `ToTypenamehere`. Any other suffix doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to make this style more consistent? Make it so that it only suggests var when it does not throw away information that might be useful for a human reading the code?

[image]

Comment: A method named `ToProgram()` returning anything other than a Program would be a gross flaw in my book.

Comment: True that but make it GetProgram it does not suggest the var.. Besides it does happen in real code that the name of the method does not match the type and in these cases I would really like to be able to see that in a PR review without having to open a IDE.